# Why am I getting this Array to String Conversion Notice

Tags: php

I am using an eCard program [here](http://www.christmasnativity.org/ecard/) to send invitations for an event and get the following notice:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /nfs/c07/h01/mnt/108712/domains/christmasnativity.org/html/ecard/include/common.inc.php
>   on line 32

Here is the code from lines 29 to 33:

```
/* Clean up request: Remove magic quotes, if the setting is enabled. */
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  foreach($_REQUEST as $name => $value) 
    $_REQUEST[$name] = stripslashes($value);
}
```

Any clues what may be causing this error notice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid running stripslashes on arrays like this

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  foreach($_REQUEST as $name => $value)
    if(!is_array($value)){
      $_REQUEST[$name] = stripslashes($value);
    }
}
```

but then the values inside an array `$value` won't get stripped.

A more complete solution would be something like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  strip_slashes_recursive($_REQUEST);
}

function strip_slashes_recursive(&$array)
{
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
    if (is_array ($value))
    {
      strip_slashes_recursive ($array[$key]);
    }
    else
    {
      $array[$key] = stripslashes($value);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the values in `$_REQUEST` is an array. This can happen if a variable uses a name such as `foo[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams says, one of the `$value`'s is an array. You can use the following to see what is an array (assuming you are/can output the results to somewhere you can see them):

```
$_REQUEST[$name] = stripslashes($value);
var_dump($value);
```